# How to match list items with values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array, it contains values [1,2].
I also have an html list

```
<ul>
<li id="1">List Item 1</li>
<li id="2">List Item 2</li>
<li id="3">List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to iterate through the array, and if a value in the array matches an ID in my list, add a class to the list item.

The output example would be

```
<ul>
<li id="1" class="active">List Item 1</li>
<li id="2" class="active">List Item 2</li>
<li id="3">List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm a bit lost on this one, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate the array into `"#1,#2"` and pass it as a selector then add class to it,

```
var arr = [1,2];   // var arr = Express.completedSteps;

$($.map(arr,function(val,_){
  return "#" + val;
}).join()).addClass('active');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/4L68b/)

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble getting this to work, though it makes complete sense to me. I am setting my array as such `var arr = $(Express.completedSteps);` which contains the values `"BillingDetails","ShippingDetails"` for example. Is there any difference when dealing with strings instead of integers?

Comment: @TheEks what `$(Express.completedSteps);` would return.?

Comment: console log shows `["AccountDetails", "BillingAddress"]`

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks for the update.! TheEks: Have a look at the update made by Mr_Green.

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you both so much! That was the ticket. Can you explain that change and what made the difference? Thanks!

Comment: @TheEks `Express.completedSteps` is a plain array and you don't need to pass it inside of `$()`. And i wonder why did you do that.?

Comment: Just following suit of the other code that had already been written in the file :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 var arr=[1,2];
 for(var i in arr){
   $("#"+arr[i]).addClass("active");
 }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/63/)

Answer (score 1):

Try out following.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var obj = [1,2,5,7];  


        $.each( obj, function( key, value )
           {
               $('li').each(function(){

              if($(this).attr('id')==value)
              {
              $('#'+value).addClass( "active" );
              }
    });
});



})
```

try out the demo here.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/104/)

Comment: This one would be really helpful for anyone looking for classes since there may be multiple on the page. Really great addition!